# Is there a way to get the member_id of a user that was just logged out?

Tags: ee2, add-on-development, hook, session-end-hook

I currently have the core file `Session.php` modified a little to keep track of login/logout information and `member_id`s - `create_new_session()` for login, `destroy()` for logout.

I realize that this can be better achieved with an extension using hooks - `member_member_login_single` after login, `member_member_logout` after logout.

The issue, though, is with the logout hook the system doesn't pass along any data ([documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/extension_hooks/module/member_auth/index.html)), so there's no way for us to know the `member_id` of the user who just logged out.

Is there a way to accomplish this at all aside from modifying core files?  I already have a hacky solution (editing core files), so I'm looking for the "right" way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Although the hook doesn't provide any information you can use, you could do a query on the exp_members table where ip_address is equal to the users ip, and sort the results by last_activity descending. Logging out should record the timestamp into the last_activity field and the ip address is updated every time a member logs in. As a result, this should then allow you to get the relevant data for that member to use in your tracking. But yes, definitely use hooks instead of hacking core files :)

Comment: Definitely less hacky than what I'm currently doing, as this would allow me to exclusively use an extension.  I'll give it a shot and report back if it works or not.  Thanks for thinking out of the box on this one!